# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycodestyle'"

Tags: python, pycodestyle

I have installed pycodestyle on my mac in the same path using

```
pip install pycodestyle
```

but when I check for its version I get-

```
    "pycodestyle" --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shashwatkhilar/tools/bin/pycodestyle", line 6, in <module>
    from pycodestyle import _main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycodestyle'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code that produced this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a project directory **demo**
2. change directory to the project directory
3. create a virtual environment **myenv**
4. Activate the virtual environment.
5. Install pycodestyle

```
mkdir demo
cd demo
python3 -m venv myen
source myenv/bin/activate
pip install pycodestyle
```

Check whether it is installed or not using any of these commands

```
pip freeze
```

or

```
pycodestyle --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using mac. I think you should have at least two versions of python, and this pip install is with another python. You can try

```
pip3 install pycodestyle
```

if that's not working try to find the correct version you want to use and set alias with

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, `pip` refers to an older version of Python. If You want to use Python 3, use the `pip3` command.

Comment: Please delete your answer. It is wrong.

Comment: No, it's true. "Pip is for python version less than 3.
and pip3 is used when you want to install packages for python version 3 or higher." source = https://python-forum.io/thread-12792.html.     If you are on a mac, pip comes pre-installed with Python 2.7. Pip3 is the Python3 version of pip.

"If you just use pip, then only the python2.7 version will be installed. You have to use pip3 for it to be installed on Python3."    source = https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-pip-and-pip3

Comment: Yes. I am using mac and pip is working I upgraded to python3. From his error message, it is clear that it is not an issue with pip/pip3.

Comment: Ok sorry so I don't know. I've tried to install pycodestyle on my Mac using pip3, and there is no problem. If you've upgraded ```pip``` to python3, as you said, the problem isn't here.